# C Application with Pthread crashes

Tags: pthreads

i have a problem with the pthread library in a C-Application for Linux.

In my Application a Thread is started over and over again. 
But I allways wait until the Thread is finished before starting it.

At some point the thread doesn't start anymore and I get an out of memory error.

The solution I found is to do a pthread_join after the thread has finished.

Can anyone tell me why the Thread doesn't end correctly?

Here is an Example Code, that causes the same Problem.
If the pthread_join isn't called the Process stops at about 380 calls of the Thread:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile uint8_t check_p1 = 0;
uint32_t stack_start;

void *thread1(void *ch)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    int i;
    int s[100000];
    char stack_end;
    srand(time(NULL) + counter);
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof (s)/sizeof(int)); i++) //do something 
    {
    s[i] = rand();
    }
    counter++;
    printf("Thread %i finished. Stacksize: %u\n", counter, ((uint32_t) (stack_start)-(uint32_t) (&stack_end)));

    check_p1 = 1; // Mark Thread as finished
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t p1;
    int counter = 0;
    stack_start = (uint32_t)&counter; // save the Address of counter
    while (1)
    {
    counter++;
    check_p1 = 0;
    printf("Start Thread %i\n", counter);
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, thread1, 0);
    while (!check_p1) // wait until thread has finished
    {
        usleep(100);
    }
    usleep(1000); // wait a little bit to be really sure that the thread is finished
    //pthread_join(p1,0); // crash without pthread_join

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly, non atomic access to an object from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution I found is to do a pthread_join after the thread has finished.

That is the *correct* solution. You *must* do that, or you leak thread resources.

> Can anyone tell me why the Thread doesn't end correctly?

It *does* end correctly, but you *must* join it in order for the thread library to know: "yes, he is really done with this thread; no need to hold resources any longer".

This is *exactly* the same reason you must use `wait` (or `waitpid`, etc.) in this loop:

```
while (1) {
  int status;
  pid_t p = fork();
  if (p == 0) exit(0);  // child
  // parent
  wait(&status);  // without this wait, you will run out of OS resources.
}
```